# Did Lady Butterfly betray the old Divine Heir?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

The description for the Sakura Droplet states:

> "A pink-colored crystal created when an Oathbound breaks their connection with a Divine Heir.
>
> Can only be used with assistance from one who has the inherent power of the Dragon's Blood."

Later after defeating Lord Genichiro Ashina we learn about another Divine Heir before Lord Kuro. Considering Lady Butterfly's age, is it possible that she betrayed him and she now has a Sakura Droplet due to it?